# "Earth" button not showing up to switch from google maps to google earth

Tags: api, google-maps, google-earth

I have looked over several samples of how to switch between google earth and google maps version 3 but I keep coming across the same problem. I can copy the code and use my own API for google maps and the google map shows up and runs fine.
The problem is that the button to switch to google earth is not showing up next to the "Satelite" and "Map" buttons. Do I need to create my own button or checkbox or something to switch between the two and if so how do I call it?
I got my example from the google library at: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/examples/earth.html
The code I copied is shown at: http://digcrust.groups.et.byu.net/GEandGMexample.html

Answer (score 0):

In order to view the Google Earth plugin on your browser, in conjunction with your maps, you need to obtain the Earth API key: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/. This example seems to mirror what you're looking for: http://earth-api-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/examples/maps-integration.html

Comment: You no longer need a specific developer-generated key but still need to load the "www.google.com/jsapi" javascript in the target HTML page.